# Подключение к MySql возвращает Unable to connect to any hosts due to exception: java.net.SocketException:

Tags: android

Не пойму в чём проблема: Почему возникает  данная ошибка?

```
 try {
                // System.out.print("String\n");
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
                String query = "select NAME, LASTNAME from myfirsttable";

                con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
                 if (con != null)Toast.makeText(this, "Connected to the database", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                else Toast.makeText(this, "Not connected to the database", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                // getting Statement object to execute query
                stmt = (Statement) con.createStatement();


                // executing SELECT query
                rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

                while (rs.next())
                {

                    String name = rs.getString("NAME");
                    String lastname = rs.getString("LASTNAME");
                    //  System.out.printf("Name: %s, Lastname: %s %n", name, lastname);
                    formatter.format("Name: %s, Lastname: %s %n", name, lastname);
                    Toast.makeText(this, formatter.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
catch (SQLException ex)
            {
                // System.out.println("Error = " + ex);
                Toast.makeText(this, "Error = " + ex, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
```

Сразу после

```
 con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
```

переходит к SQLException с указанной ошибкой.
В манифесте прописано

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

На серверной части разрешения даны для пользователя. С ПК других подключается без проблем.
И где можно почитать про перехват ошибок SQLException? Что бы на телефоне выдавать информативные ошибки, а не просто окно что приложение закрывается.
Спасибо.

Comment: Странно, теперь другая ошибка: 
     Communications link failure

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

Last packet sent to the server was 1 ms ago.

Comment: покажите как url выглядит

Comment: А через пару раз возвращается ошибка как в теме. Не понятно...

 private static final String url = "jdbc:mysql://10.239.16.74:3306/myfirsbase";
    private static final String user = "root";
    private static final String password = "root";

Comment: проверьте есть ли у вас на самом устройстве подключение к интернету?

Comment: Подключение осуществляется в сети локальной. Причина какая-то другая.

Comment: на чем тестируете андроид клиент? стандартный эмулятор, GM или реальное устройство? и где установлена бд, на этой же машине или на другой в локальной сети?

Comment: Используется реальное устройство, БД находится на ПК в локальной сети. Телефон подключается к этой же сети через wi-fi. С ПК телефон пингуется, а вот с телефона неизвестно, видит ли он ПК. Пропинговать нечем.

Comment: Из последних наблюдений: Постоянная ошибка "The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server." А эта ошибка если я правильно понял возникает в случае когда клиент не видит сервера. Возможно надо указать ещё какие-то разрешения в AndroidManifest?

Comment: Не понятно... с телефона пингуется ПК с БД. Почему же тогда нет соединения. Если выключить MySQL сервер и попытаться подключиться с ПК то возникает аналогичная ошибка. А с телефона постоянно выдает её. Может у Андроида установлены ограничения безопасности на прямые подключения? И нужен root.

Comment: В общем получается следующее. Официального ответа от Гугла не нашёл, но на заграничных сайтах очень много пишут вот что:

Android cannot connect directly to the database server. 

А что бы всё работало как хочется, нужен веб-сервер промежуточный. Хотя мне не понятно, зачем промежуточный сервер. Пишут что так не безопасно. Но пароли можно и не хранить локально.